# Using constructors with multiple files Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I'm trying to implement some oop in my javascript program, so basically I have this project structure

```
src
|_model
|    |_Amministratore.js
|_main.js
```

I have the following code in Amministratore.js

```
///Rappresenta un amministratore di sistema
const Storage = require("../PersistanceStorage");

function Amministratore(info) {

  this.email = info.email;
  this.password = info.password;
  this.nome = info.nome;
  this.cognome = info.cognome;
  this.role = "admin";

  this.aggiungiID = function(ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
  };

  //Ritorna il path del nodo
  this.path = function() {
    return "Admin";
  };

  //Restituisce la versione memorizzabile nel
  this.getUploadableVersion = function() {
    return {
      [ID]: {
        nome: this.nome,
        cognome: this.cognome
      }
    };
  };
```

Now in my main.js I have this piece of code:

```
exports.postAdmin = functions.region(REGION).https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const adminData = req.body;

  if (adminData === null || adminData === undefined) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send(impacchettaInformazioni(null, "must provide a body!", 400));
  }

  const admin = new model.Amministratore(adminData);

  return admin
    .postAmministratore()
    .then(function() {
      return res
        .status(200)
        .send(impacchettaInformazioni(null, "Admin created!", 200));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return rej
        .status(500)
        .send(impacchettaInformazioni(null, err.message, "500"));
    });

});
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: model.Amministratore is not a constructor
    at exports.postAdmin.functions.region.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:311:17)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Am I missing something? Do I need some kind of module.export like when I export some functions inside another file? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is that `model` coming from and what is `model.Amministratore`?

Comment: Exactly, You need to export functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the constructor function at `Amministratore.js`

```
exports.Amministratore = Amministratore
```

Then require it at your `main.js` file

```
const model = require('./model/Amministratore.js')
```